# How to adding string before just selected item at WheelPicker (React Native JS)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to add '$' sign before the just **Selected** WheelPicker item.
But my code is add '$' before front of All Picker Item.
How can i fix it?
Thanks for all answer.
[image: Problem ScreenShot]

```js
export default class yks extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  
  this.state = {
    ttSelectedItem : 20,
    itemList: numberList
  };
}
    onPickerSelect (index, selectedItem) {
        this.setState({
            [selectedItem] : index,
        })
    }
    onAddItem = () => {
        var name = 'XYZ'
        if (this.state.itemList.indexOf(name) == -1) {
            this.state.itemList.push(name)
        }
        this.setState({
            selectedItem: this.state.itemList.indexOf(name),
        })
    }
    }
    }
```

**Render WheelPicker:**

```js
                <Picker style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                    selectedValue={this.state.ttSelectedItem}
                    itemStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"#e88554", fontSize:26, }}
                    onValueChange={(index) => this.onPickerSelect(index, 'ttSelectedItem')}>  
                        {this.state.itemList.map((value, i) => (
                            <PickerItem label={'$' + value} value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
                        ))}
                </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Picker style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
    selectedValue={this.state.ttSelectedItem}
    itemStyle={{width: "100%", height: "100%", color:"#e88554", fontSize:26, }}
    onValueChange={(index) => this.onPickerSelect(index, 'ttSelectedItem')}>  
        {this.state.itemList.map((value, i) => (
            <PickerItem 
                label={(this.state.ttSelectedItem === i ? '$' : '') + value} 
                value={i} key={"money"+value}/>
        ))}
</Picker>
```